# How do i get a list of all files with a specific extension with c++ without <dirent.h> on windows

Tags: c++, windows

How to get a list of all files with a specific extension with c++ without <dirent.h> on windows.
dirent.h is not working on visual studio 2019, is there any other way i could get a list of all files in a directory.

for example of the list would be

```
file.txt
secode.txt
hello.txt
h.txt
```

if not then could i get dirent.h working in visual studio 2019.

Comment: Use [`<filesystem>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem) if your compiler is new enough. If not, you probably want [`FindFirstFile`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-findfirstfilea) or  [`FindFirstFileExA`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-findfirstfileexa) along with the matching`FindNextFile`.

Comment: For the `<filesystem>` version, look at [`std::filesystem::directory_iterator`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/directory_iterator). Good usage example at the bottom of the page. The `FindFirstFile` brothers are well documented at the given links, complete with examples.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to work ith file system using c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43900462/how-to-work-ith-file-system-using-c)

Comment: The mentioned dupe is not referring to extensions. And the dupes accepted-answer is using "dirent.h".  Another example of a bad judgement by the guardians of the grail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With C++17 this is also easily possible without boost. I tested the below example with VS2019.

Please see the example below. Reading the complete file list is just a very short one-liner:

```
std::vector fileList (fs::directory_iterator(startPath), {});
```

Usage of range constructor for `std::vector`.

We can define the std::vector without template argument. The compiler can deduce the argument from the given function parameters. This feature is called CTAD ("class template argument deduction").

Additionally, you can see that I do not use the "end()"-iterator explicitely.

This iterator will be constructed from the empty brace-enclosed initializer list with the correct type, because it will be deduced to be the same as the type of the first argument due to the std::vector constructor requiring that.

Of course you could also check sub directories with the `fs::recursive_directory_iterator`

Finding the extension is then quite simple. You can of course check additional file/path attributes as well. No problem.

Please see a complete working example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <filesystem>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>

namespace fs = std::filesystem;

int main() {

    // The start path
    const fs::path startPath{ "C:\\temp\\" };
    // And the extension to look for
    const std::string extension{ ".txt" };

    // Get all directory entries into our fileList vector
    std::vector fileList (fs::directory_iterator(startPath), {});

    // Evaluate. Go through all directory entries
    for (const fs::directory_entry& de : fileList) {

        // Get path as string
        std::string p{ de.path().string() };

        // Check if it ends with the given extension
        if (p.substr(p.size() - extension.size(), extension.size()) == extension)
            std::cout << p << "\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Additional solution using `std::transform` and `std::copy_if`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <filesystem>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>

namespace fs = std::filesystem;

int main() {

    // The start path
    const fs::path startPath{ "C:\\temp\\" };
    // And the extension to look for
    const std::string extension{ ".txt" };

    std::vector<std::string> files{};

    // Get all path names as string
    std::transform(fs::directory_iterator(startPath), {}, std::back_inserter(files), [](const fs::directory_entry & de) { return de.path().string(); });

    // Output all files with extension
    std::copy_if(files.begin(), files.end(), std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(std::cout,"\n"), [&extension](const std::string & p) {
        return (p.substr(p.size() - extension.size(), extension.size()) == extension); });

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

if you have boost you can use boost::filesystem
here is an example of getting all image in jpg extension.

```
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>
#include <boost/filesystem/path.hpp>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
using namespace boost::filesystem;
using std::string;
using std::vector;
    void GetAllImageFromDir(path& dir, vector<path>& all_dir_images)
{
    string str(".jpg");             // store paths,
    vector<path> all_dir_files;

    std::copy(directory_iterator(dir), directory_iterator(), back_inserter(all_dir_files));

    for (int k = 0; k < all_dir_files.size(); ++k )
    {

        if (all_dir_files[k].filename_is_dot() || all_dir_files[k].filename_is_dot_dot() || !is_regular_file(all_dir_files[k]))
        {
            continue;
        }
        else
        {
            if (is_regular_file(all_dir_files[k]))
            {
                string extension = boost::filesystem::extension(all_dir_files[k].string());

                    if (extension.compare(str) == 0)
                    {
                        all_dir_images.push_back(all_dir_files[k]);
                    }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: can you show all the libraries you use in the code

Comment: I edit with what I remember if this not compile I will check what missing

Comment: cannot open source file "boost/filesystem.hpp"                                                            cannot open source "boost/filesystem/path.hpp"

Comment: you need to build boost and add it to yore compilation https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_1/more/getting_started/unix-variants.html